# Android animation runs on multiple layouts and not just the clicked one

Tags: android, android-animation

I have 3 RelativeLayouts that are generated dynamically. They all have the same ID and onclick goes to this function:

```
public void catPanelOnClick(View vw) {
    //vw.findViewById(R.id.catPanel).startAnimation(buttonClick);
    vw.startAnimation(buttonClick);
}
```

Works fine if the first view is clicked. However when you click panel 2 both 1 and 2 will animate. Then when clicking panel 3 all 3 will animate. Should I be cancelling the applied animation when it completes somehow?

Comment: Please show us more of your code, especially how you generate the `RelativeLayout`s and more about how you load and apply the animation.

Comment: It seems you are using view animations? Those shouldn't really be used any more. I guess you are loading the animation once then apply the same animation every time you want to animate a `View`? That might be part of the problem.